# Create a .mdb without MS Access or ADOX

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-2010

I'm using dephi 2010, which is getting difficult with me about installing the ADOX components. So I was wondering if there is a way to create a .mdb file without the use of the ADOXCatalog.

-Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think you need to install adox components?  I believe it is part of the Jet since XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done without using an ADOXCatalog.

1. Place a `TAdoConnection` and e.g. a `TAdoCommand` on a form or datamodule.  Set the `TAdoCommand`'s `Connection` property to the `TAdoConnection`.
2. Then, in the `AdoConnection`'s `ConnectionString` builder, select  Microsoft OLE DB Driver for ODBC.  Then, follow the ODBC wizard to set up a new MDB database.  As you follow that through you will be able to create a File DSN (unless you are running Delphi as adminstrator), select the Access Jet driver, specify the database path (making sure it is somewhere writeable) and name, and then the wizard presents you with a button to click to create the MDB file.

Although it is not in English, there is a video here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_2hrER9oho

which shows you exactly how to do this.  The ODBC connection string wizard should give you the option to create a new datasource and present you with a list like this to choose from:

[image: ODBC New datasource driver list]

3. Set the `TAdoCommand'`s CommandText to something like

   `create table ATable (AName TEXT(40))`

and call its `Execute` method at r/time to create a one-column table.

Btw, you could equally well use a `TAdoQuery` instead of the `TAdoCommand` component using its `Sql` property instead of the `TAdoCommand`'s `CommandText`property, and you should be able to use any valid DDL statements to define the tables in the database.

Comment: Thanks, I've got to setting the DNS and putting in the path but I'm not seeing an option to select the Access jet driver.

Comment: Sorry, I think that must be a problem with your machine, rather than the method.  I've added a screenshot showing the list of drivers on my machine.  Do you see any of the drivers listed?

Comment: That was my fault mate, I was looking at the wrong thing. Your method works perfectly. Just a quick question, if I run this on a different machine will it create that .mdb or will I have to go into the ConectionString builder? Apologies if that's a stupid question.

Comment: No, it's a good question.  The method in my answer relies on the ODBC wizard (which is actually part of Windows) to create the table, so as to avoid having to use the ADOXCatalogue in Delphi code.  So you would either have to go through the same rigmarole of using it to create the MDB file, or copy the .MDB file onto the other machine as well as the ODBC registry key for its DSN.  Personally, I've never done this though because I always use MS Sql Server database rather than Access ones.

Comment: Ah right I may have to look into using MS SQL or MYSQL then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm biased of course, but ime MS Sql Server + ADO components "just work" 99.99% of the time.  I've never run into a problem with either of them personally.  Also, it's worth taking a look at Firebird, the freeware equivalent of Interbase.

Comment: So when using MS Sql how would you set it up for the user to press a button and have it send the command to create a database, what would ADOConnection connect to?

Comment: Well, a Delphi app isn't the ideal tool for creating a Sql Server database (Sql Server Management Studio is much better for this because of the wide variety of configuration options available).  For an MS Sql Server, basically the connection string specifies a) whether you want to use the ODBC or OLE DB driver (now deprecated but preferable imo to the ODBC one); b) the server name; c) user name and password.  Everything else (incl database) is optional, so you can easily connect to an existing server using Delphi Ado components and send it the DDL Sql to create a new database.

Comment: Btw, using Sql Server Management Studio rather than a Delphi app avoids you having to know/look up the necessary DDL statements to create a database and tables etc within it.

Comment: I'm just going to be using the database to store some user details for a game, so the reason I'm using a delphi app to create the db is really just to keep it as self contained as possible.

Comment: You could also just include an empty database as a resource in your program and the save that to disc if needed. That would be the easy solution.

Comment: "is really just to keep it as self contained as possible"  For that sort of thing, any of the DBMSs we've been talking about would be overkill.  Have a look at TClientDataSet for local tables of modest size (<50k records) or even Sqlite (though its loose column-typing drives me nuts).